# Tengo problemas a escribir una base de datos

Tags: soporte, preguntas

Quiero formular una consulta sobre un código que hice, no logro crear una base de datos en Titanium, y no se incluir el código que me da errores.
Gracias

Pregunta en el sitio principal

- [Como crear base de datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/89895/65)

Comment: Hola Gemita. ¿Cuál sería el texto de tu pregunta? Sin eso, no podemos ayudarte. Eso o realmente no entiendo qué es lo que quieres preguntar.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que nos sabes incluir el código? ¿Es muy largo? En cuanto a código que da errores, es conveniente que revises [Ejemplo, mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hola, si que es un poco largo, intente añadirlo aqui y me a dicho que tiene 88 caracteres de mas. Gracias

Comment: @gemita Hola te sugiero publiques tu pregunta aquì https://es.stackoverflow.com/ que es lo adecuado.

Comment: gemita: Lo primero a hacer es "debuggear" tu código, es decir, tratar de identificar dónde está el problema y reproducirlo con el menor código posible, esto con la finalidad de identificar claramente cuál es el problema. Los detalles están en el enlace que puse en mi comentario anterior. Algo que puedes hacer es poner en [SOes] una descripción breve de lo que estas intentando hacer y si hay un mensaje derror, incluir este forma textual y agregar la línea de código en la que ocurre. Los conocedores de Titanium, te podrán decir si con eso es suficiente para orientarte.

Comment: Por cierto, ¿ por titanium te refieres a http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium ?

Comment: Hola.. si agregas tu codigo de error, creo que veo tu problema, y una vez que pongas eso podemos reabrir tu pregunta y puedo contestarla

Answer (score 2):

Pues eres bienvenido a hacer esa pregunta. No te desanimes porque la hayan puesto en espera. Eso no significa que se rechace tu pregunta. Solo significa que queremos que la edites mejorando algunos detalles.

La gente que hay en Stack Overflow en realidad es bastante amistosa a poco que cooperes un poco con ellos. 
Por ejemplo, gbianchi te pide el código de error. Lo hace porque quiere ayudarte y necesita ese dato para hacerlo.
Esta es la tónica general con la mayoría de usuarios. Si cierran tu pregunta, esta o cualquier otra, sencillamente pon un comentario preguntando qué le falta a la pregunta. Y añádelo cuando te lo digan. Verás como pronto tu pregunta vuelve a estar abierta.